# Selecting a unique row

Tags: mysql

How can I achieve this kind of uniqueness.. no column unique only the row, ex. ID # 2 has a record in October, ID # 2 must not have 2 info with res_month = 'October'

```
res_id | res_month | res_year
   1   | September | 2013
   2   | September | 2013
   3   | September | 2013
   4   | September | 2013 
   2   | October   | 2013
   3   | October   | 2013
   4   | October   | 2013
```

Comment: Add unique constraint on res_id column

Comment: Do you want to make sure that unique records will be input in the res_id column of your DB (as assumed by Deepak) or you want to get unique records in your VB.NET application even though the res_id column might contain repeated values? (as assumed by asantaballa)? If you meant the first option, you should delete the VB.NET tag to avoid confusions. Please, clarify.

Comment: I see.. Bear in mind that the usual proceeding in these cases (column consisting in unique integers) is relying on "auto increment" (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html). PS: perhaps you should try to be a bit more communicative with people who intend to help you (answerers and myself). You don't even need to do it  to show your respect and appreciation, but just for cold, practical reasons: communicating quickly and accurately what you want tends to speed up the helping process appreciably (also don't forget that helpers might not feel like helping you again).

Answer (score 1):

You can build a `UNIQUE KEY` contraint over multiple fields:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl ADD UNIQUE KEY foo (res_id, res_month, res_year);
```

*(`foo` is just the name for the contraint - you may want to choose a more explanatory name)*

This constraint ensures that each combination of `res_id`, `res_month` and `res_year` can only occur once.

With this in place an `INSERT` with an already stored combination yields a `Unique constraint failed` error. In your example, this would fail because the combination already exists:

```
INSERT INTO tbl (res_id, res_month, res_year) VALUES (2, 'October', '2013');
```

Answer (score 0):

Add unique constraint on res_id column
This won't allow duplicate values in res_id column